# How to generate embedded code in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to generate an embedded code from my ReactJS application. I really don't know how can I achieve such functionality?

for example, I want to generate a code which can be used in another website using the iframe, same like youtube embedded code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why doesn't this have the javascript tag? reactjs is not a standalone tag

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with below steps.

1.Add DOM element container to contain your component

```
<!-- ... Your HTML code ... -->

<div id="example_container"></div>

<!-- ...Your HTML code ... -->
```

The ***div*** tag will help us to find out this element from our script code to render our desired react code within it.
2. Add your react script.**Please make sure you load react before your script.**

```
<!-- Load react scripts -->
<!-- Load our React component. -->
  <script src="example.js"></script>
```

3. After your code in `example.js` which has `ExampleReactClass` extends `React.Component`and `const e = React.createElement;`  add the below lines to fix your code in mentioned `<div>`

```
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#example_container');
ReactDOM.render(e(ExampleReactClass), domContainer);
```

Hope it will work!!

Comment: thanks for your comment. let me try if it works for me :). I will not forget to accept and upvote your answer.

Comment: Please do find the updated edit for better clarity for other parameters :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has example of youtube, lets start with that.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.yoursite.com/embed/h04NnnUApaM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Our main concern is the `src` attribute, rest of the iframe attributes can be considered if needed.

To make things easier we need to have Router to handle the embed url request from iframe

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Add a route to handle `/embed/h04NnnUApaM`

```
<Route path='/embed/:id' component={YourComponent}/>
```

Get the embed id in `YourComponent` like this `props.match.params.number`

render the component, and it should show in the iframe.

**Generate embed code**

Depends on what you want to embed.

```
<textarea>{this.state.embedCode}<textarea>
```

`embedCode` will be something like this for the above example (id depends on what you need to render your component from the embeded page)

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.yoursite.com/embed/h04NnnUApaM"></iframe>
```